# How to find all <li>'s within a specific <ul> class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

**Environment:**

Beautiful Soup 4

Python 2.7.5

**Logic:**

'find_all' `<li>` instances that are within a `<ul>` with a class of `my_class` eg:

```
<ul class='my_class'>
<li>thing one</li>
<li>thing two</li>
</ul>
```

Clarification:  Just get the 'text' between the `<li>` tags.

**Python Code:**

(The find_all below is not correct, I am just putting it in context)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import re

# open original file
fo = open('file.php', 'r')
# convert to string
fo_string = fo.read()
# close original file
fo.close()
# create beautiful soup object from fo_string
bs_fo_string = BeautifulSoup(fo_string, "lxml")
# get rid of html comments
my_comments = bs_fo_string.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[my_comment.extract() for my_comment in my_comments]

my_li_list = bs_fo_string.find_all('ul', 'my_class')

print my_li_list
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This?

```
>>> html = """<ul class='my_class'>
... <li>thing one</li>
... <li>thing two</li>
... </ul>"""
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'my_class'}):
...     for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
...             print litag.text
... 
thing one
thing two
```

### Explanation:

`soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'my_class'})` finds all the `ul` tags with a class of `my_class`.

We then find all the `li` tags in those `ul` tags, and print the content of the tag.

Comment: thank you, i understand this logic, when i change `fo_string` to a beautiful soup object with `bs_fo_string = BeautifulSoup(fo_string, "lxml")` and print `bs_fo_string`, i can see that `>` has been turned to `&gt;` and `<` has been changed to `&lt;`.  so using `find_all` is bringing up an empty list as it cannot find either `ul` or `li`.  does anyone know why this conversion to character entities is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: @user1063287 What does `fo_string` look like? Edit your question to add it in

Comment: my bad, malformed html, class names in `fo_string` were missing closing `"`! code is now working. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick with BeautifulSoup3, don't have 4 on this machine.

```
>>> [li.string for li in bs_fo_string.find('ul', {'class': 'my_class'}).findAll('li')]
[u'thing one', u'thing two']
```

The idea is to search first for the ul with 'my_class' class, and then findAll of the li's within that ul.

If you had additional ul's with the same class you might want to use a findAll on the ul search as well, and change the list comprehension to be nested.