# Beautiful soup - How to get <li> items from div class and <ul> without any class name for ul and without ID

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The input data is as below, where it has multiple `ul` tags as same to scrape in python beautiful soup.

`<div class="column one-second"><p></p> <ul> <li>Commercial automobile</li> <li>Excess liability</li> <li>General liability</li> <li>Inland marine (cargo)</li> </ul> <p></p></div> <div class="column one-second"><p></p> <ul> <li>Professional Liability</li> <li>Property</li> <li>Workers’ compensation</li> </ul> <p></p></div>`

```
To get the listed items from `ul` tag using beautiful soup library, I tried this but did not work:

    amusements_soup.find_all('li', attrs={'id': 'menu-item-16'})


    amusements_soup.find_all('div',{'class':'column one-second'})


    ul = amusements_soup.find("h2", text="Services & Solutions").find_next_sibling("ul")

expected output :

> Commercial automobile
> 
> Excess liability
> 
> General liability
>
> Inland marine 
>
> Professional Liability
> 
> Workers’ compensation
```

Comment: what about using just `lis = soup.find_all('li');

uls = soup.find_all('ul')`?

Comment: but i need only li items for particular class as here:
 <div class="column one-second"><p></p>
<ul>
<li>Commercial automobile</li>
<li>Excess liability</li>
<li>General liability</li>
<li>Inland marine (cargo)</li>
</ul>
<p></p></div>

Comment: if you want only the `li` items for a particular class, then why you don't want to use any `class` or `ID` attributes? that is their purpose.. to find only those items.

Comment: there is no ID attribute available!!

Comment: then where are you getting the `class` attribute from? I don't see any `class` attribute either, but you are using it

Comment: is there any sample where i can get some knowledge in it!

Comment: Yes there are lots of samples in the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and other SO questions such as [How to find all <li>'s within a specific <ul> class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246963/how-to-find-all-lis-within-a-specific-ul-class)

Comment: can we have a quick chat!

Comment: this is how it looks exacty:

<div class="column one-second"><p></p>
<ul>
<li>Commercial automobile</li>
<li>Excess liability</li>
<li>General liability</li>
<li>Inland marine (cargo)</li>
</ul>
<p></p></div>
<div class="column one-second"><p></p>
<ul>
<li>Professional Liability</li>
<li>Property</li>
<li>Workers’ compensation</li>
</ul>
<p></p></div>

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55462647/edit) and include that HTML code into the question

Comment: anything? @davedwards

Comment: have you tried `for item in amusements_soup.find_all('div',{'class':'column one-second'}):
    for li in item.find_all('li'):
        print(li.text)`? <-- this is basically the same as bleand's answer below

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `amusements_soup` contains the HTML that you mention, this should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = '<div class="column one-second"><p></p> <ul> <li>Commercial automobile</li> <li>Excess liability</li> <li>General liability</li> <li>Inland marine (cargo)</li> </ul> <p></p></div> <div class="column one-second"><p></p> <ul> <li>Professional Liability</li> <li>Property</li> <li>Workers’ compensation</li> </ul> <p></p></div>'
amusements_soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
for item in amusements_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'column one-second'}):
    sub_items = item.findAll('li')
    for sub_item in sub_items:
        print(sub_item.text)
```

Output:

```
Commercial automobile
Excess liability
General liability
Inland marine (cargo)
Professional Liability
Property
Workers’ compensation
```

If this is not working for you, you'll have to check that `amusements_soup` is actually what you think it is

Answer (score 0):

Same thing with class and type selector with descendant combinator using a list comprehension

```
results = [item.text for item in amusements_soup.select('.one-second li')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "example---url"
req = urlopen(url)
page_html = req.read()
req.close()
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
table_item = html_soup.find('div', class_="class_name")

files = input("                Give Me File Name            \n>>>")
fileName = files + ".csv"
f = open(fileName, "w")
head = 'Title, Price'
for item in table_item:
    title = table_item.find('div', class_="class_name").text
    price = table_item.find('div', class_="class_name").text
    f.write(title + ','+ price)

print(title)
print(price)
print(table_item)
""" 
maybe it will help, and i hope it helps.
Note : I'm see YouTube Video Link This
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIjXuYRLge8`enter code here
"""
```